# How can a contract have funds on another chain?

Tags: solidity, evm

I've been looking at some random contracts on EVM compatible chains and noticed some of them have funds on the Ethereum network or another EVM network.

For example, https://polygonscan.com/address/0xddaad340b0f1ef65169ae5e41a8b10776a75482d has balance on Ethereum as regular address.

How is this possible, and, could the owner of this contract retrieve those funds since smart contracts don't have a private key.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a contract at the same address on multiple chains, since the address depends only on the deployer and its nonce (unless it was deployed by another contract using EIP-1014). So, in your example, the deployer can decide to deploy a contract on Ethereum to recover the funds.

However if an address is a contract on a chain, then it can't be an EOA (regular address) on another chain. If you see cases where they have funds on multiple chains it's usually because users mistakenly transferred tokens  on the wrong chain.